# Updating license plate on Trusted Traveler/Sentri

Tags: usa, automobiles, trusted-traveler, sentri

Our car is registered through Trusted Traveler to be used in the Sentri Lanes at the US southern border.  We've just renewed registration and were issued new plates (with new plate number).

I know I can update the plate number for the vehicle in the TTP dashboard, through Manage Vehicles > Edit, but before I do that I need to know how long it will take.

When adding an entirely new/separate vehicle there can be a period of several weeks before the new vehicle is approved for use, and you can NOT use that vehicle through Sentri until approved.

However, I'm unsure whether there is wait period for approval of new plates on an existing vehicle (everything else about the vehicle remains the same).

Is there an approval wait period for changing plates in Trusted Traveler, or is it instant and could be used same day?  If not instant, then I'll need to plan out the timing so it doesn't impact on our border crossing plans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was unable to find an answer, so I just updated it in the Trusted Traveler portal and hoped for the best.  I was able to edit the vehicle details, change the plate number and click Submit.  The next screen detailed the changes I'd made (changed plate number) and had a "Back to Dashboard" button.

Clicking that button just sent me back to the main TTP screen.  There were no messages about needing to wait for approval etc., and the vehicle details now show the new plate number.

So I won't know for sure until next time we take the car through Sentri, however it certainly looks like there was no approval required, and that the change seems to have been instant.